# why <br/> are not stored in database while importing csv in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

why html tags are not stored in database while importing csv in sugarcrm
Please help me, i am using sugar version 6.5.16 . While importing CSV data with html tag ,data is not storing in database.

Comment: You didn't give us enough information, so here..

http://www.sugaruk.co.uk/blog/sugarcrm-how-import-data

Comment: give some more information

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM doesn't allow importing of HTML into its database, as it could cause a XSS (Cross Site Scripting vulnerability). If you need to insert a newline, just place a \n inside the CSV file. **NOTE** most fields in SugarCRM don't support multi-line.

Comment: i tried it but its not working , if i am writing like &lt;br/ &gt; its converting into <br/> and its getting saved. But i want to give <br/> directly in CSV

Comment: Ok i got my answer , I removed strip_tag from importer.php and its working now . Thanks

Comment: I suggest to not remove strip_tag, it would allow someone to inject HTML into your SugarCRM database, which is NOT recommended, it could lead to a compromise of your server